# How can I delete a thread running a blocking socket function in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading

I have a problem, where I have created a thread which is running a blocking socket function (e.g. accept) and I need to shutdown the thread and  close the socket without getting a bunch of errors so that I can use the socket again. I have created the following example to illustrate the problem:

```
import threading
import socket
 
def accept_clients(a_socket):
    print("Accepting clients!")
    while True:
        a_socket.accept()
        print("A client connected!")
 
my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 6000))
my_socket.listen(10)
threading.Thread(target=accept_clients, args=(my_socket,)).start()
```

When running this code I get the output `Accepting clients!` and the thread accepts clients like expected and prints out the correct messages.

However when it comes time to close the thread I run the following line of code:

```
my_socket.close()
```

I get these errors:

```
Exception in thread 
Thread-1 (accept_clients):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aliam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\aliam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 4, in accept_clients
  File "C:\Users\aliam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 294, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

I'm assuming that these errors are being caused because the accept method is still running in the thread while I've tried to close the socket.

I was wondering if there was a way I could close the thread and socket without getting a bunch of errors.

Comment: The easy way to handle this is use `try`/`except` to catch this error and exit the thread cleanly.

Comment: That's arguably **not** an error. It's an expected exception when you try to accept a connection on a socket that's been closed. try/except is your friend here